# Not getting expected data for Laravel JSON:API

Tags: laravel, json-api

I am trying to create an API based on the following two Models:

**Product.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Commerce;

use ...

class Product extends Model {

    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;

    public mixed $id;

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'title', 'default_variation', 'status'];

    /**
    +     * @return HasMany
    +     */
    public function productVariations() : HasMany {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Commerce\ProductVariation');
    }

    public function defaultVariation() : HasOne {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Commerce\ProductVariation', 'default_variation');
    }
}
```

**ProductVariation.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Commerce;

use ...

class ProductVariation extends Model {
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'product_id', 'sku', 'title', 'price', 'status'];

    public function product() : BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

I have configured the JSON:API according to the documents, as best I can tell:

**routes/api.php**

```
<?php

use ...

JsonApiRoute::server('v2')->prefix('v2')->resources(function ($server) {
    $server->resource('products', JsonApiController::class)->readOnly();
    $server->resource('product-variations', JsonApiController::class)->readOnly();
});
```

**ProductSchema.php**

```
<?php
// For authentication see ProductPolicy
namespace App\JsonApi\V2\Products;

use ...

class ProductSchema extends Schema
{
    public static string $model = Product::class;
    public function fields(): array
    {
        return [
            ID::make(),
            DateTime::make('createdAt')->sortable()->readOnly(),
            DateTime::make('updatedAt')->sortable()->readOnly(),
            Str::make('title'),
            Number::make('user_id'),
            Number::make('defaultVariation'),
            HasOne::make('defaultVariation', 'default_variation'),
            Boolean::make('status'),
            HasMany::make('productVariations')
        ];
    }

    public function filters(): array
    {
        return [
            WhereIdIn::make($this),
        ];
    }

    public function pagination(): ?Paginator
    {
        return PagePagination::make();
    }

}
```

**ProductVariationSchema.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\JsonApi\V2\ProductVariations;

use ...

class ProductVariationSchema extends Schema
{

    public static string $model = ProductVariation::class;

    public function fields(): array
    {
        return [
            ID::make(),
            DateTime::make('createdAt')->sortable()->readOnly(),
            DateTime::make('updatedAt')->sortable()->readOnly(),
            Number::make('userId'),
            Number::make('productId'),
            Str::make('sku'),
            Str::make('title'),
            Number::make('price'),
            Boolean::make('status'),
            BelongsTo::make('product')
        ];
    }


    public function filters(): array
    {
        return [
            WhereIdIn::make($this),
        ];
    }

    public function pagination(): ?Paginator
    {
        return PagePagination::make();
    }

}
```

With some dummy data in the database, I can access the endpoint `/api/v2/products` and receive the following:

```
{
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "products",
            "id": "3",
            "attributes": {
                "createdAt": null,
                "updatedAt": null,
                "title": "foo-product",
                "user_id": 1,
                "status": 1
            },
            "relationships": {
                "defaultVariation": {
                    "links": {
                        "related": "domain/api/v2/products/3/default-variation",
                        "self": "domain/api/v2/products/3/relationships/default-variation"
                    }
                },
                "productVariations": {
                    "links": {
                        "related": "domain/api/v2/products/3/product-variations",
                        "self": "domain/api/v2/products/3/relationships/product-variations"
                    }
                }
            },
            "links": {
                "self": "domain/api/v2/products/3"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

`/api/v2/product-variations`

```
{
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "product-variations",
            "id": "3",
            "attributes": {
                "createdAt": null,
                "updatedAt": null,
                "userId": 1,
                "productId": 3,
                "sku": "foo-bar",
                "title": "foo bar ",
                "price": "11.11",
                "status": 1
            },
            "relationships": {
                "product": {
                    "links": {
                        "related": "domain/api/v2/product-variations/3/product",
                        "self": "domain/api/v2/product-variations/3/relationships/product"
                    }
                }
            },
            "links": {
                "self": "domain/api/v2/product-variations/3"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However, if I try `api/v2/products/3/product-variations` or `/api/v2/products/3/relationships/product-variations` I get a 404 error:

```
{
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "status": "404",
            "title": "Not Found"
        }
    ]
}
```

Additionally, if I run a test I also get a 404 but I do see that the variations are correctly related:
[image]

I think that somewhere I have misconfigured something, but this is my first time doing this in Laravel so I might be completely missing a configuration also.

Comment: I never used the laravel json api library but I think you should check docs for [Defining Relationships](https://laraveljsonapi.io/docs/1.0/routing/). I don't see that you define `->relationships(...` call in `routes/api.php`

Comment: Made some progress based on your comment.  If I change the route to `$server
        ->resource('products', JsonApiController::class)
        ->relationships(function ($relationships) {
            $relationships->hasMany('product-variations');
        })->readOnly();` I now see the product variations endpoint in the route list.  However, I'm getting a 401 on it so I must not have the policy setup correctly for this yet.

Comment: Ok, that led me to https://laraveljsonapi.io/docs/1.0/requests/authorization.html#relationship-authorization and I seem to be good to go

Comment: Awesome :) Check given answer or maybe add your own on what helped to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You only set a JsonApiRoute (starting with api) and prefix('v2') meaning `api/v2` group. In this group you add 2 more product-variations meaning `/api/v2/product-variations` and products `/api/v2/products`. So anything else don't exists and laravel returns 404.

You need to add

> $server->resource('products/{id}/product-variations', JsonApiController::class)->readOnly();

for `api/v2/products/3/product-variations`

and

> $server->resource('products/{id}/relationships/product-variations', JsonApiController::class)->readOnly();

for `/api/v2/products/3/relationships/product-variations`

Also you can add `(int $id)` in your controller methods to read this id you pass.

Comment: If I just add `$server->resource('products/{id}/product-variations', JsonApiController::class)->readOnly();` I get there `No schema for JSON:API resource type products/{id}/product-variations.`.  The `ProductVariationSchema` does exist

Comment: In the initial question you ask why you get 404 and i answers that question. If you need additional better open another one with more specific title.

Comment: simply adding what you did there did not resolve the issue - that actually isn't necessary.  If you update your answer to include that I need to add the relationships and the policy then I'll accept.

Comment: I don't think this answer is valid at all. It does not add a related resource link to the existing API endpoints for a resource. Instead it registers it as a separate resource. Please have a look at comments on original question, which includes a link to the relevant section of Laravel JSON:API documentation.